# Symfony 3. Использование entity manager в конструкторе

Tags: php, symfony, symfony3

У меня есть функция, которая проверяет залогинился ли пользователь.

```
private function checkUserAuth(){
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $session = new Session();
    $repository = $em->getRepository('LoginLoginBundle:Users');
    if($session->has('login')){
        $login = $session->get('login');
        $email = $login->getEmail();
        $password = $login->getPassword();
        $user = $repository->findOneBy(array('email' => $email, 'password' => $password));
        if ($user) {
            $this->_commonOptions['userName'] = $user->getName();
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

Что бы не вызывать ее в каждом методе, хотел засунуть в конструктор. Но в конструкторе это не срабатывает, потому что, как я понял, не срабатывает вызов entity manager?
Подскажите как правильно можно это реализовать, что бы избавится от повторяющегося кода?

Comment: В каком конструктере и где именно вы вставляете? может прокатит parent:__construct();

Comment: @Naumov вставляю в class AdminController extends Controller

Comment: Какой прототип конструктура класса Controller? var_dump($this->getDoctrine());

Comment: @Naumov не совсем понимаю как это узнать. 
При var_dump и вообще любой попытке обратиться в конструкторе к $this->getDoctrine() выдается Error: Call to a member function has() on a non-object

Comment: Ну вот и копайте в этом направление, т.е. попробуй parent:__construct(); в начале твоего __construct() написать

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если хотите использовать DI в контроллерах, настройте работу с ними как с сервисами: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/service.html

Если (например) оригинальный интерфейс не разрешает использование дополнительного параметра в конструкторе, всегда можно добавить сеттер и геттер (с приватным свойством) и использовать операцию [`calls`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#optional-dependencies-setter-injection) в конфигурации сервиса.

И второй момент: все действия с авторизацией и аутентификацией следует реализовывать через имеющийся механизм [security](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html). Ваша задача - тривиальная, загрузка пользователя из БД по логину/паролю с сессионным хранилищем. Это подробно описано в соответствующей статье документации: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html